# Ruby alias_method or a new method?

Tags: ruby

Is there a reason why I should use alias_method like so:

```
alias_method :author, :name
```

instead of simply doing the following?

```
def author
self.name
end
```

Comment: @sawa what about `Module.instance_method :alias_method`

Comment: @nicooga Okay, I got what you mean. pickwick, My previous comment was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias_method` will actually create a copy of the method for you. If you happened to later on redefine `name` with some new behaviour, `author` would still retain the original behaviour. This is useful if you want to preserve the original behaviour. See [the docs for alias_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method)

> Makes new_name a new copy of the method old_name. This can be used to retain access to methods that are overridden.

```
module Mod
  alias_method :orig_exit, :exit
  def exit(code=0)
    puts "Exiting with code #{code}"
    orig_exit(code)
  end
end
include Mod
exit(99) # => Exiting with code(99)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is cleaner, and one of the thing Ruby enforces are conventions.

Also, if you would change the number of arguments to the name method, than you would have to change it on the author method, while with `method_alias` you wouldn't have to change it in multiple places.

Nevertheless, if you want to use the method you wrote and you're sure lets say the number of arguments won't change (which i'm sure it won't in your case), you can do that and it's not wrong, but also you don't need the `self` part, you can just write it like this:

```
def author
  name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing the full method takes a substantial amount of time. In addition, `alias_method` can be used when you want to duplicate a more in depth method.

Finally, there is one subtlety.

```
class Foo
  def bar1
    "This is bar 1"
  end

  alias :bar2, :bar1

  def bar1
    "This is sparta!"
  end
end

puts Foo.new.bar1 # => "This is sparta!"
puts Foo.new.bar2 # => "This is bar 1"
```

The above shows that aliasing always points to the first method. This is important when considering inheritance.

[See the Docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method). They say it makes a copy of the old method.

Comment: Ruby 2.0 throws a syntax error in REPL, whines at the "," between the two method name. And you don't need the `puts` at `Foo.new.bar1` because the methods already print the string.